# Converting unknown Java types to Rust types

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface

I am trying to take a HashMap from Java into Rust and convert it into an internal object, matching data types and all. The HashMap in java is a `HashMap<String, Object>` where the `Object` could be any data type including another `HashMap<String, Object>`.

I'm having a difficult time determining what type of object a `JObject` is, and I am blocked on how to convert a `JObject` to something like a `JString`.

As you can see I've barely gotten anywhere with it, but as a first pass I'd just like to return the string value of either a `String`, `Integer`, or `Date` (where `Date` would be the string value of `Date.getTime()`).

```
static DATE_CLASS: &str = "java/util/Date";
static INTEGER_CLASS: &str = "java/lang/Integer";
static STRING_CLASS: &str = "java/lang/String";

fn get_string_value(env: &JNIEnv, obj: JObject) -> String {
    let ret = String::new();

    if env.is_instance_of(obj, STRING_CLASS).unwrap() {
        let ret2 = env.call_method(obj, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", &[]).unwrap();
        // Got a JValue- now what?
    }

    if env.is_instance_of(obj, INTEGER_CLASS).unwrap() {
        let ret2 = env.call_method(obj, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", &[]).unwrap();
        // Got a JValue- now what?
    }

    if env.is_instance_of(obj, INTEGER_CLASS).unwrap() {
        let ret2 = env.call_method(obj, "getTime", "()Ljava/lang/String;", &[]).unwrap();
        // Got a JValue- now what?
    }

    ret
}
```

I think the way I'm *supposed* to do this (but please correct me if not), is to check if the `JObject` is an instance of any of these classes by their fully qualified paths. Once I know what type they are, I can call a method on them with `env.call_method`. The result is a `JValue`, which can return some primitive types.

[image]

I'm assuming I'm supposed to be using these unless I'm expecting another object to be returned, in which case I'd use-

```
let message_ref = env.auto_local(ret2).as_obj();
```

Then I could call another method if I needed to. But as far as I know I can't then convert that into a JString if I wanted to. However, that's also the only way I know how to get a rust string out of a JString so far, using:

```
let s: String = env.get_string(a_j_string).expect("Couldn't get java string").into();
```

Am I going about this right?

How do I convert a JValue to a String?

Am I correct that I should use `auto_local` to convert a `JValue` to a `JObject`, and that would allow me to call methods on it again?

If I'm supposed to use the primitive type `jchar` to get the value of `toString`- how do I convert that to `&str` or `String`?

Edit:

With @Chris Jester-Young's help I was able to get both a `jobj_to_string` and `jobj_to_int` functions working.

```
static INTEGER_CLASS: &str = "java/lang/Integer";
static STRING_CLASS: &str = "java/lang/String";

fn get_liquid_value(env: &JNIEnv, obj: JObject) -> LiquidValue {
    let mut value = LiquidValue::Nil;

    if env.is_instance_of(obj, STRING_CLASS).unwrap() {
        match jobj_to_string(env, obj) {
            Some(str) => {
                value = LiquidValue::Scalar(LiquidScalar::from(str));
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }

    if env.is_instance_of(obj, INTEGER_CLASS).unwrap() {
        match jobj_to_i32(env, obj) {
            Some(int) => {
                value = LiquidValue::Scalar(LiquidScalar::from(int));
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }

    value
}

fn jobj_to_string(env: &JNIEnv, obj: JObject) -> Option<String> {
    let mut result = Option::None;

    match env.call_method(obj, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", &[]) {
        Result::Ok(jvalue) => {
            match jvalue.l() {
                Result::Ok(jobject) => {
                    let string = String::from(env.get_string(jobject.into()).unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
                    result = Option::Some(string);
                },
                _ => {}
            }
        },
        _ => {}
    };

    result
}

fn jobj_to_i32(env: &JNIEnv, obj: JObject) -> Option<i32> {
    let mut result = Option::None;

    match env.call_method(obj, "intValue", "()I", &[]) {
        Ok(jvalue) => {
            match jvalue.i() {
                Ok(int) => {
                    result = Option::Some(int.to_owned());
                },
                _ => {}
            }
        },
        _ => {}
    }

    result
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `jni` crate, `JObject` and `JString` are just wrappers around JNI's `jobject` and `jstring`. You can "cast" a `JObject` into a `JString` using the `From` trait. e.g., `JString::from(my_jobject)` or `my_jobject.into()`. You do have to do a `JNIEnv::is_instance_of` check first, though, if you're at all unsure if the object is actually a string.

To your question about `JValue`, the result of `toString` is a string, which in the JVM universe, is an object type, not a primitive type. So you can just use the `JValue::l` accessor (you don't need to use `auto_local` from what I can tell). Since we know the result is a string, you can just cast the result to a `JString` directly (as described above), and then call `JNIEnv::get_string` to get a `JavaStr` object, that you can convert to a Rust string using the `From` trait.

Putting it all together, we get the following (not tested, but it compiles for me at least):

```rust
fn get_string_value(env: &JNIEnv, obj: JObject<'_>) -> Result<String> {
    let result = env.call_method(obj, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", &[])?.l()?;
    Ok(env.get_string(result.into())?.into())
}
```